# jdbcTemplate and raw JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jdbctemplate

Suppose I query a table which contains raw `json` in a column, or create json myself with a subquery like this:

```
select
p.name,
(select json_build_array(json_build_object('num', a.num, 'city', a.city)) from address a where a.id = p.addr) as addr
from person p;
```

How can I instruct Spring's `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` not to escape
the `addr` column but leave it alone?

So far it insists returning me something like this:

```
[{
    name: "John",
    addr: {
        type: "json",
        value: "{"num" : "123", "city" : "Luxembourg"}"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working solution.

Service:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public String getRawJson() {
    String sql = "select json_agg(row_to_json(json)) from ( "
    + "select "
    + "p.id, "
    + "p.name, "
    + "(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(c))) from ( "
    + " ... some subselect ... "
    + ") c ) as subq "
    + "from person p "
    + "where type = :type "
    + ") json";

    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource("type", 1);

    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, params, String.class);
}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/json", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getRawJson() {
    return miscService.getRawJson();
}
```

The key is the combination of `json_agg` and `row_to_json / array_to_json` plus returning a `String` to avoid any type conversions.